# error: file 'C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\ftpmirror.py' does not exist

Tags: python

When I execute `python setup.py install` in Windows 10, I see this output:

```
C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_scripts
creating build
creating build\scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting byteyears.py -> build\scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting checkpyc.py -> build\scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting copytime.py -> build\scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting crlf.py -> build\scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting dutree.py -> build\scripts-2.7
error: file 'C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\ftpmirror.py' does not exist
```

Comment: Python is already installed, so what exactly are you trying to install here?

Comment: WMI(Windows Management Instrumentation)

Comment: You're running installation from the Python directory directly... Are you sure this is the correct way to install that module?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I'm already solve this problem with "pip install pypiwin32".thanks  all~

Comment: Close the question then!

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem very easy. Just add/copy missing file from https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/ftpmirror.py to the path `C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts` and execute

```
python setup.py install
```

again.